# Get verb from noun Wordnet python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to get the verb from a noun with Wordnet in python.
Here is the code:

```
nouns = ["slip", "frustration"]
def nominalization(noun_word):
   set_of_related_verbs = set()

   for lemma in wn.lemmas(wn.morphy(noun_word, wn.NOUN), pos="n"):
      for related_form in lemma.derivationally_related_forms():
        set_of_related_verbs.add(related_form)
   return set_of_related_verbs

for word in nouns:
    set_of_words = nominalization(word)
    if len(set_of_words) >= 1:
        print word + "+++"
        print set_of_words
```

I need only verbs but I get the others pos too for example:
slip+++
set([Lemma('slippery.**a**.01.slippy'), Lemma('err.v.01.slip')])

How can I change this?

If I use the line:

```
for synset in wn.synsets(related_form.name(), pos=wn.VERB):
```

I get only the verbs but some verbs can be not related to my noun for example:
acquiring+++
set([Synset('**get**.v.01'), Synset('**assume**.v.03'), Synset('**grow**.v.08'), Synset('acquire.v.04'), Synset('acquire.v.05'), Synset('**develop**.v.03'), Synset('**learn**.v.01')])

Answer (score 1):

You can derive the lemmas and related word forms from which you can extract the verbs:

```
import nltk as nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

lem = wn.lemmas('frustration')
print lem
```

Result:

```
[Lemma('frustration.n.01.frustration'), Lemma('frustration.n.02.frustration'), Lemma('frustration.n.03.frustration')]
```

From which you can get the verbs like this:

```
related_forms = [lem[i].derivationally_related_forms() for i in range(len(lem))]
print related_forms
```

Result:

```
[[Lemma('thwart.v.01.frustrate')], [Lemma('thwart.v.01.frustrate')], [Lemma('thwart.v.01.frustrate'), Lemma('torment.v.02.frustrate')]]
```

Comment: But then I get only the results for lem[0] (Lemma('creation.n.01.creation')) and I need a related forms for all of them (Lemma('creation.n.01.creation'), Lemma('creation.n.02.creation'), Lemma('creation.n.03.creation'))

Comment: AND the lem[0] can be the other word (probably from synset?) for example lem[0] from "expiation" is "atonement":
[Lemma('atonement.n.01.expiation'), Lemma('expiation.n.02.expiation')]

Comment: Yes it can be the other word. You can check for the first character to get the exact verb form

Comment: I get other pos with this code: [Lemma('steal.v.02.slip'), Lemma('skid.v.04.slip'), Lemma('dislocate.v.01.slip'), **Lemma('slippery.a.01.slippy')**] :(

Comment: do you want direct verb form of the particular word?

Comment: what if I would like to get only verbs in the final result? the returned set seems to contain other forms such as nouns and adjectives.